# Setting up sessions on express app on multiple dynos heroku app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, heroku, express

I have implemented some user authentication on a single Heroku dyno using express (node.js)+ mongodb and everything is working fine. However, when I increase the number of dynos (more than 1), I cannot login, I keep being redirected on my login page, meaning my session hasn't been set. Here is my code:

checkCookies = function(req, res, next) {

```
  if(req.session.user){
   res.locals.user = req.session.user;
   next();
  }
  else{
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
};
app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: '0GBlJZ9EKBt2Zbi2flRPvztczCewBxXK',
  cookie: {httpOnly: true, maxAge:14*24*60*60*1000}
  }));
```

What is the best solution to handle shared session on express/node.js using mongodb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

connect-mongo should meet your needs: https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo

Comment: Thanks a lot! All set up in 10 minutes

Answer (score 6):

The above answers are misleading in that they imply you can't share cookie based sessions across multiple dynos on Heroku.

I'm able to to use cookie based sessions across multiple dynos if I use [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) as opposed to [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session).  What's missing from the first post in this thread is the secret value is NOT passed to the cookie parser.  This means that node will assign a random hash to the parser each time the process restarts or when a new dyno spins up.

Doing the following works for me:

```js
app.use(express.cookieParser('0GBlJZ9EKBt2Zbi2flRPvztczCewBxXK'))
app.use(express.session({
  secret: '0GBlJZ9EKBt2Zbi2flRPvztczCewBxXK',
  cookie: { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
}))
```

Comment: Great answer, good to know about being able to specify the cookie secret

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cookieSession` instead of `express.session`? Like in the documentation `const cookieSession = require('cookie-session')`

Answer (score 5):

Use [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) module with express.

```
var http    = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    session = require('connect-mongo')(express)
```

And then in your workers setup session to store externally. Code below will use session from mongo, cookies and extra headers in order to allow cross-domain and jsonp.

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({
    store: new session({
      db: 'sessions'
    }),
    secret: 'yoursecret',
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 // 1 day
    }
  }));
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });
  app.set('jsonp callback', true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining further! Can you tell me the advantage of allowing cross domain and jsonp? Or tell me where I can read something about it? I google it and nothing help came out

Comment: If you will have example.com website, and will call from its JS AJAX request to api.com - which will be you node application, then it will not allow to do this in most of browsers due to security limitation.
You have enable this on server side to allow access from another domains, and you have to add additionally JSONP and use it if you need older browsers support.
If you want to have even session cookies data shared, you will need to add extra bit to your ajax requests, for jQuery it will be `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }`.  
Check more info here: http://goo.gl/Y1XK0

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a quick copy/paste solution that is a bit more updated then basically follow the link Dan posted above or just use my snippet below:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); // if using mongoose

mongoose.connect(connectionOptions); // if using mongoose

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
    secret: '0GBlJZ9EKBt2Zbi2flRPvztczCewBxXK',
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 // 1 day
    }
}));
```